# Splitting each commit by file?

Tags: git

I've accumulated a lot of git commits for my project. As the first step in cleaning the repo up, I'd like to split *every* commit into two commits: one which only touches a particular file /some/directory/file, and another which touches everything else.

Since the git history is fairly long, I'd like to avoid doing this manually.

Some approaches that I've thought about (but haven't actually tried out) are:

- using `git rebase --exec` with a script that does the splitting.
- using `filter-branch`. (don't have much familiarity with this tool)

However, since this seems to me like a fairly common problem, I thought I would check here before attempting to reinvent the wheel. Is there any automated way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You are on the way, what you have tried is the way to do it.
As you found out you have 2 main options:

---

#### [`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) aka: `squash` (manual procedure)

```
// Manipulate any commit by editing it and commitign again
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

---

> Since the git history is fairly long, I'd like to avoid doing this manually.

#### git filter-branch

- Read this article which address your problem
  [How to tear apart a repository: the Git way](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/04/tear-apart-repository-git-way/)
- `git filter-branch` will run on every commit specified in the condition and then you can do what ever you wish with it (**via script**) and not manually.
- [Here](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-git-repo) is another very useful article about `filter-branch`
- [Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

---

#### sample

```
// Remove any given file from commits 
// Now you can commit it again into a new commit

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f <file name> HEAD
```